# Packard Bell desktop computer running linux will not boot from USB - Trying to install Ubuntu Studio 19.04

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu Studio 19.04 on a Packard Bell imedia S2870 with Ubuntu Studio 16.04 already installed.
I've changed the boot order to USB first, but the computer won't boot from the usb.
Also the only way I can enter the BIOS if after doing an hard reset of the computer ( pushing on the power button for about 10 seconds, and then upplugging the computer for 30 seconds).
Thanks for your help

The USB stick installer was created using Unetbootin, and I've used it to install Ubuntu on another computer.
Bellow is a picture of the manufacturer tag

Comment: How did you create the USB stick installer? Have you tried using the usb stick on different machine?

Comment: It has UEFI, not BIOS, and probably with Fast Boot enabled which explains the dificulty in accessing the settings (it's always possible though). How did you burned the USB?

Comment: Can't find that model at Packard Bell'a website under Group = Desktop and Series = iMedia or iMedia XS http://www.packardbell.com/pb/en/GB/content/download  so would you please run this _sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer_ then add the results to your question with [edit]? Please do not use Add Comment as old comments can get shoved off screen by new comments.